# Pointcut expression for argument in any position

Tags: java, aspectj

```
@Before(value = "@annotation(OwnershipCheck) && args(enquiry)")
public void checkOwnership(Enquiry enquiry) throws Throwable
{
}
```

The above expression will match for any method with the OwnershipCheck annotation and takes an enquiry as a parameter.

How can I extend this expression for any method with the OwnershipCheck annotation and takes an enquiry in any position with or without another parameters.

That is, needs to match

```
@OwnershipCheck    
public void one(Enquiry enquiry)

@OwnershipCheck
public void two(Object obj, Enquiry enquiry)

@OwnershipCheck
public void three(Enquiry enquiry, Object ob)

@OwnershipCheck
public void four(Object obj, Enquiry enquiry, Object other)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did this:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(protections) && args(request,..)")
private void httpRequestAsFirstParam(Protections protections, HttpServletRequest request){}

@Pointcut("@annotation(protections) && args(..,request)")
private void httpRequestAsLastParam(Protections protections, HttpServletRequest request){}

@Pointcut("@annotation(protections) && args(*,request,..)")
private void httpRequestAsSecondParam(Protections protections, HttpServletRequest request){}

@Around("httpRequestAsFirstParam(protections, request) " +
        "|| httpRequestAsLastParam(protections, request) " +
        "|| httpRequestAsSecondParam(protections, request)")
public Object protect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Protections protections, HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable {
    //...
}
```

You can't do `args(.., enquiry, ..)`, but it is possible with `args(*, enquiry, ..)` and combine with first and last argument matchers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Before(value = "@annotation(OwnershipCheck) && args(.., enquiry, ..)")
public void checkOwnership(Enquiry enquiry) throws Throwable
{ }
```

But I am not sure if this is supported in @AspectJ.  So, you may need to do this instead:

```
before(Enquiry enquiry) : 
    execution(@OwnershipCheck * *(.., Enquiry, ..)) && args(.., enquiry, ..) { }
```

Comment: @AspectJ doesn't support it. And if it did, would it only work for method four?

Comment: '..' means 0 or more matches, so the syntax above would support all 4 variants.